# How to get rid of this Background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I got rather simple question...
Do you know a time efficient way to cut out this object?. I basically don't want to do it manually.
Thank you all for your ideas :)

[image]

Comment: See duplicate links above, using the Red channel for this image does a [decent job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hukk8.png) -- roughly 1 minute of work, if that.

Comment: Magic eraser set to high tolerance and contigous box unchecked...